VS Code Terminal Slow to Start and Respond When Using Code Runner Extension
I have been using vs code for a while now ,but recently I am facing the issue of a laggy and a very slow terminal response while executing .js files ,even a single line js program like console.log("hello world); takes hell lot of time to get displayed in the terminal ,tried every possible solution found in youtube videos still not fixed,can anyone help me  fix this issue?
I am having a asus tuf gaming f15 11th gen 16gb Ram laptop.
Tried every set of solution from yt videos and even Uninstalled the vs code couple of times.

Welcome to SO! You mean the problem is related to the Code Runner extension? What is your configuration of it? Did you have look into the extension's issues to see if others have the same problem (for example: this seems related) and already found a solution?
